# Capture stdout in variable and redirect stderr

Tags: bash

This is not working:

```
result=`./myscript.sh $@` 2> /dev/null
```

As `stderr` is still appearing on my screen.  I'm guessing the assignment is getting grouped improperly, but I really don't know how to do both of these operations at once (in particular without creating temp files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
result=`./myscript.sh $@ 2> /dev/null`
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
result=$(./myscript.sh "$@" 2> /dev/null)
```